# How to generate a table row with a flexible height

Tags: jasper-reports, height

I have a word report generated by jasperreport that i need to edit by entering more text in a specific paragraph, my problem is that this paragraph is generated under a table row and this row is générated with a fixed height and it don't stretch with its content when I am typing text, so when I exceed the last row I do not see anymore what I am typing.

Please do you have any idea about how can I generate a jasperreport table row  or paragraph with a flexible height depending on its content ?

The only code that I think useful to know is the part of report that generate the specific paragraph :

```
<textField>
<reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="443" width="445" height="20"/>
<textElement/>
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{fieldValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: can you please provide code ?

Comment: a part of code was added on the post. thanks

Comment: Check whether it will works or not ?
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None" hyperlinkTarget="Self" > <reportElement style="dNew" mode="Opaque" x="55" y="0" width="55" height="19" key="value-1" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" positionType="Float" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/> <box></box> <textElement> <font/> </textElement> <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{value1}]]></textFieldExpression> </textField>

Comment: It gives an exception on execution : [27590840:00011-06430] 24/06/2014 09:40:44   HTTP JVM: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not resolve style(s): dNew

Comment: can you please provide the stack trace about exception?

Comment: which jar file you are using for jasper reports? please use the updated jar file.

Comment: The report is probably using JasperReport Functions and you probably didn't install jasperreports-functions-5.5.1.jar in your buildpath.

Comment: I use Jasper 3.7.6 and can not change it for the regressions that could cause

Comment: please update all the jasper's jar file.http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%205.5.1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56179/discussion-between-lotfiction-and-keval-trivedi).